# How to get all values from a form?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am definitely sure doing something wrong which I didn't resolve. I have a form component which are includes several textfield, radio button as well as windows. If I used the following code :

```
console.log(Discounts.getForm().getValues());

// Discount is form name which is defined like below
var Discounts = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    ...
}
```

I can see all values except `grid panel` which is included `window` component ( to tell the truth I can't see all other window values!).

The component tree like below :

```
+-- FORM PANEL ( layout card )
  |
  +-- CARD LAYOUT - 1
  | |
  | +- COMBOBOX
  | +- TEXTFIELD
  |
  +-- CARD LAYOUT - 2
  | |
  | +- WINDOW
  |  |
  |  +- GRID PANEL
  |
  +-- CARD LAYOUT - 3
  | |
  | +- RADIO GROUP
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

For instance, I would like to get `winArticle` window field values as well as `Discount` forms together.

PS : The code is very large so that I putted JSFiddle.

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/c8749/)

Comment: `getValues` returns form element values... windows and panels clearly are not form elements. What kind of values are you expecting? And a window in a card layout seems strange to me.

Comment: Dear Lauren, I would like to get textfield values that available in the window. I can put `form` component inside of the window but nothing happen. I believe there is a simple solution but I didn't find yet!

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. When you fix it, I recommend removing the extraneous configuration not necessary for demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Dear Eric, the app has many json store which is connecting to the MySQL server. Therefore I didn't put that part of the code.

Comment: There's too much code in your fiddle to make sense of. Put together a smaller test case that demonstrates the issue, I doubt anyone is going to wade through all that code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a formpanel in a formpanel, by giving the child formpanel an itemId and using component queries like `Discounts.down('#yourchildformpanelitemid').getValues()` you could probably get its values...

However, since your code in no way maintainable, my advice, **refactor/restructure your code and use MVC structure**. From Sencha:

> Large client side applications have always been hard to write, hard to
>   organize and hard to maintain. They tend to quickly grow out of
>   control as you add more functionality and developers to a project. Ext
>   JS 4 comes with a new application architecture that not only organizes
>   your code but reduces the amount you have to write.

You will need to restructure your code and define your components separately. this will make your app maintainable. In your case the formpanel you create would be a separate component and have its own controller, thus enabling you to use the same formpanel elsewhere.

Also, read the following article from Sencha, ExtJS practices to avoid:
http://www.sencha.com/blog/top-10-ext-js-development-practices-to-avoid/

Most of these tips (if not all) are applicable to your code.
For example, you are nesting components like crazy. Most of the nesting is unnecessary. For example:

```
...
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'form',
        items: new Ext.Panel({
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    ...
```

`xtype: 'form'` creates a form panel, why on earth create a panel inside?

More on ExtJS MVC Architecture:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: While I can't say that MVC is the grand solution here, the asker does need to simplify some overengineering.

Comment: Dear Lauren, you are correct about nesting `form` component but it was just a test purpose. As I specified above, I can't get field values that available in window so that I wanted to put extra `form` component to try something, sorry about that.